# Use BufferedReader and InputStream together

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I use a BufferedReader to read lines from an InputStream. When I read something directly from the InputStream, the BufferedReader ignores my read and continues reading at the same location. Is it possible to prevent this behavior? If not what is a good practice to do this?

PS: Here's my code:

```
byte[] ba = new byte[1024*1024];
int off = 0;
int len = 0;
do {
    len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    in.read(ba, off, len);
    br.readLine();
    off += len;
} while(len > 0);
```

`in` is my inputstream and `br` my bufferedreader.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: better to share code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: are you just trying to make sure that the br and in are at the same point in the file, while only reading with the inputstream? why is this necessary for your use case to have two different streams

Comment: what is your inputStream, where does it get data from? User input? File?

Comment: @sunrize920 it's not possible to read bytes from a bufferedreader so i need to read them directly from the inputstream

Comment: Probably best to use the bufferedreader for all the reading. Still seems bizarre. Could you show the code where you are opening these streams?

Comment: what is the format of the file? is it text file or binary file?

Comment: @sunrize920 `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` The inputstream is given as a parameter, it isn't used before.

Comment: @user3218114 i need byte arrays and no char arrays.

Comment: I saw [this LineReader class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Alinereadingwrapperthatworkswithbytestreams.htm) when I was scavenging around.

Comment: you might have better luck with a bufferedinputstream since you are wanting to deal with raw bytes. Also, the format of the stream you are reading may be the cause of the problem. From your code, it looks like lines are read in pairs, where the first line is just an int telling you how long the next line will be?

Comment: I recommend you just use a bufferedinputstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from a BufferedReader and an InputStream at the same time is not possible. If you need binary data, you should use multiple readLine() calls.

Here's my new code:

```
byte[] ba = new byte[1024*1024];
int off = 0;
int len = 0;
do {
    len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().split(";" , 2)[0],16);
    for (int cur = 0; cur < len;) {
        byte[] line0 = br.readLine().getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < line0.length; i++) {
            ba[off+cur+i] = line0[i];
        }
        cur += line0.length;
        if(cur < len) {
            ba[off+cur] = '\n';
            cur++;
        }
    }
    off += len;
} while(len > 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

> If not what is a good practice to do this?

This is not a good approach to read by 2 stream at a time for same file. You have to use just one stream.

`BufferedReader` is used for `character` stream  whereas `InputStream` is used for `binary` stream.

> A binary stream doesn't have `readLine()` method that is only available in `character` stream.

Comment: I like to read bytes from the stream, because i can't handle char arrays in the rest of my code.

Comment: as I mentioned in the end byte steam doesn't have `readLine()` method.

Comment: are you crating the file using program? You can use [`readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29) method

Comment: You haven't answered my question. 1. Is it binary file? 2. Are you creating the file via program?

Comment: 1. It's binary. But it contains lines with information i need as non binary values. 2. I get the data from a webserver.

Comment: if you uses `writeUTF` while writing the file then you can use `readUTF` to read a string.

Comment: I can't influence the way the data is created.

Comment: you can use `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` and convert the string in `int` or `byte[]`

Comment: glad to know it. post it as your own answer to make it helpful for others.

Answer (score -2):

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try
{
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = null;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
         //process lines here
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if(bufferedReader != null)
    {
        try
        {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a general usage of BufferedReader (which, by the way, would be about half as long if it used a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement).  It does not try to read directly from the InputStream and therefore does not address the question at all.

Comment: @VGR in that case, I misinterpreted the question, because if he wants to read bytes and bytes only, then I'm not sure why he is trying to use a `Reader` in the first place.

Comment: He wants to do both, from a single source.