# Want to view Array

Tags: android, arrays, textview

On button click i want to fill the textview with my array in same activity
I have CSV file path which i have taken in to two arrays one with number and one with name now i want those number and name array to view in the same activity

```
public void uploadfile(View view) {
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile);
    Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, FullPath, 2000).show();
    String[] name = null;
    String[] number = null;
    if(FullPath != null) {
        /* CSV UPLOADER */
        try {
            File csvfile = new File(FullPath);
            FileInputStream csvStream = new FileInputStream(csvfile);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvStream));
            String line;

            int iCount=0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                        name[iCount] = RowData[0];
                        number[iCount] = RowData[1];
                        iCount++;
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*CSV Uploader Finish*/
        /*View CSV into an array*/
        int arraySize = name.length;
        /* Not getting Idea From Here How to fill text view with My array number and name */

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to view array in textview in the same activity on upload button click

Comment: You need to build up a string to display the information in your textview. Loop through your arrays and use something like a StringBuilder to concatenate all the values you wish to be displayed. Once you are finished with this you can use setText() on the TextView to display your string.

Comment: I want to view multiple data with one textview

Comment: You should be closing the bufferedReader like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996050/use-bufferedreader-and-inputstream-together/24996192#24996192 in order to prevent memory leaks from occuring in case of exception

Comment: zhuinden but thats not what i want. I just want to view my array in the same activity without redirecting to another page

Comment: You should use ArrayList, because sometimes you don't know size of your csv file. So instead of defining array go for ArrayList.

Comment: But thats not my question please be on point and give me the answer for viewing the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to concatenate your arrays and create a String from it to use in your TextView. You need to modify it to cater for your needs.

```
final int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
final String[] names = new String[] { "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6" };

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("Show number and name data:");
stringBuilder.append("\n\n");

for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
    stringBuilder.append("number:").append(String.valueOf(numbers[counter]));
    stringBuilder.append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("name:").append(String.valueOf(names[counter]));
    stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
}

String stringForTextView = stringBuilder.toString();

Log.d(TAG, "TextView data: " + stringForTextView);
```

Edit: I've decided to include a working example you can use

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView arrayData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.arrayData);

        final int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        final String[] names = new String[] { "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6" };

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append("Show number and name data:");
        stringBuilder.append("\n\n");

        for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
            stringBuilder.append("number:").append(String.valueOf(numbers[counter]));
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            stringBuilder.append("name:").append(String.valueOf(names[counter]));
            stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
        }

        String stringForTextView = stringBuilder.toString();

        arrayData.setText(stringForTextView);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arrayData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where should i use id name of textview?

Comment: In the onCreate method of your activity you need to create an instance of your TextView: TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById<YOUR_ID>); Then when you click the button you need to build up your string as explained with the code above and then use: yourTextView.setText(<YOUR STRING>);

Comment: yourTextView.setText(<YOUR STRING>);
In loop??

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a very basic example of how to output the arrays to a textview.