# Want to view array on same activity

Tags: android, arraylist

On Upload click I am populating the array list and after populating i want to view that in the same actvity I dont want to call any other activity. means after clicking on upload i want to add data and show on the same activity uploadfile Dont want to call any of the other activity to view. I dont care if its textview or anyother view I am okay with any otherview too

```
    public void uploadfile(View view){
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile);
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(FullPath != null)
        {
                    /* CSV UPLOADER */
            try{
                File csvfile = new File(FullPath);
                FileInputStream csvStream = new FileInputStream(csvfile);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvStream));
                String line;
                String[] rowData = null;
                int iCount=0;
                String dataRow = in.readLine();
                        while (dataRow != null){
                            String[] RowData = dataRow.split(",");
                            name.add(new String(RowData[0]));
                            number.add(new String(RowData[1]));
                            dataRow = in.readLine();
                            iCount++;
            }
                        in.close();
                        Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "CSV Has uploaded", 2000).show();
                        setContentView(R.layout.new_message);
                       ListViewName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerName);
                       ListViewNumber = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, e.toString(), 2000).show();
            }
            /*CSV Uploader Finish*/

            /*View CSV into an array*/
/*Want To view array List in textview or anything but not on the different page but on the same page*/


        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "No File Selected", 2000).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is any different than this [Want to view Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014619/want-to-view-array), which you posted yesterday?

Comment: Yes its different I have use array list now and want to populate with arraylist

Comment: Its on onCreate method while i dont want to view on onCreate i want to view when Upload Button is Click and then want to populate on the same activity without redirecting to another activity

Comment: "On Upload click I am populating the array list and after populating i want to view that in the same actvity" You already have onClick functionality so simply iterate over the list and use the stringbuilder to create a string which you can set to the textview as shown in your other post?

Comment: I have tried but its not working in my case dont know why so it will be greatfull if u put some example code

Comment: uploadfile is an onclick actvity only

Comment: My belief is that you don't comprehend the basics of android or java. I would suggest that you start with simple onClick tutorials and understanding the life-cycle of activities. That would be enough for you to solve this issue.

Comment: `int arraySize = name.length;
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      for(int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++){
       stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(name[counter]));
       stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(number[counter]));`

I already tried this

Comment: This conversation is leading no way, if you don't know how to iterative over an `ArrayList` i highly suggest you start with basic Java tutorials.

Comment: I am leading no where because i just want to view my array in ListView and till now i got nothing searching for hours 
`ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listName);
       ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewMessage.this,  R.id.listName, name);
       listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`

Here is what i try

Comment: My google search was "ListView tutorial", I have no clue what your searched to not find anything.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Dont you think that is what i already tried

Comment: Then you didn't follow the tutorial, it works. If you are struggling with the tutorial, ask your question specifically to that problem you are facing with stacktrace of error and code (But google it and look on stackoverflow first!). StackOverFlow is a site to answer Questions regarding programming problems, not asking for others to implement functionality that you wish to have.